# Printed filesizes of files being written not updating?

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, filesize, tcpdump

I'm working on a shell script which does multiple tcpdumps in the background and then waits for the user to terminate. While waiting, I'd like for the script to print out the size of the folder where the .pcap files are being written. So far I've been getting the same size printed out even though the files are getting larger as the tcpdump command keeps running.

```
while true; do
echo ""
du -hcs <path>/<folder_name>
echo "Press enter to stop all traces: "
if read -rsn1 -t 5;
then
    break
fi
echo ""
```

done

Answer (score 0):

Try using `watch`

`watch -n1 "du -hcs <path>/<folder_name>"`

this will print the size each second

Comment: Thanks, but using the `watch` command gives me a periodic printout which hangs until escaped with Ctrl+C. This way following commands never execute which is a problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was with the tcpdump command, adding `-U` before `-w`  to tcpdump solved the problem.